# Git merge issues with Composer.lock

Tags: 8, composer

We have a simple setup.

We update our drupal 8 sites on a local machine using `composer update`

we commit the lock file and json file and push to a gitlab git repo

We then pull to a staging server where we run `composer install --no-dev`

This has worked great until now, however, we have run in to an issue I do not understand. On one specific site, no others, the git pull ALWAYS triggers a confict on the lock and json files. No new changes are applied and instead we get a mess of merge conflicts in the lock file.

I do not want to run the update on the staging server. I just want to pull my version controlled lock and json files and install. Is I try to reset --HARD on the merge I end up breaking the entire site and have to revert to a backup...

What would cause this issue? Why is my `composer.lock` file specifically continuing to get merge conflicts? I never run update on the remote server.

What steps can I take to identify the cause?

Comment: Asking if anybody had the same issue is polling. Instead ask a true, objective, not too broad, question.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like some one has changed the `composer.lock` on the staging server. Each time you resolve a merge conflict a new commit is made.
In case you don't push the new commit, each time you run `git pull` a new conflict will be caused.

A step to see what causes the first merge conflict would be `git diff composer.lock`.

Comment: What's started happening now is exactly this as it's the only way to get the updated lock file on to the server. I would like to have it explicitly just replace that file the file from the repo but no strategy is working. `git reset --HARD` and other such resets are just throwing errors or reproducing merge conflicts. All I want is the remote file to replace the local file.

Comment: What's about a kind of git pull force: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files

Comment: forcing is not working. It still inserts the merge conflicts.